# Setting up NAT for multiple isolated networks with iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I have a gateway machine connected to multiple internal networks that I would like to set up NAT on. The catch, though, is that these networks need to be isolated from each other, which I haven't been able to figure out. Here's my configuration:

eth0: 192.168.1.0/28 (upstream), gateway is assigned 192.168.1.1
eth1: 192.168.1.16/28 (downstream 1), gateway is assigned 192.168.1.16
eth2: 192.168.1.32/28 (downstream 2), gateway is assigned 192.168.1.32

So far, I've configured iptables to allow on default chains:

```
iptables -P INPUT ALLOW
iptables -P OUTPUT ALLOW
iptables -P FORWARD ALLOW
```

Then, I've enabled IP forwarding in the kernel and set up iptables:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

However, this configuration allows one machine on eth1 to access another machine on eth2, even though I haven't explicitly specified a rule to allow this. How do I isolate these networks, or at most only allow access to certain hosts/ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the policy of the `FORWARD` chain to `ALLOW`, so even if nothing in the chain matches, the traffic will be allowed.

You probably should set it to `DROP` instead.

Comment: Ok, I modified the FORWARD chain to drop with iptables -P FORWARD DROP. However, this causes NAT connectivity to break since there isn't a rule forwarding eth0 back to eth1 or eth2, so after adding iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT, it seems to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the response to M. Hampton, you have to keep the forwarding feature one for the NAT to work.

As a quick hack, I'd try to block the forwarding in-between the internal subnets, eg. add those commands to yours :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j DENY
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j DENY
```

That will be messy with 3 internal subnets, as you will have 6 blocking rules, and quite scary for 4 :).